# Is it bad practice to use Functions in OOP?

Tags: python, oop

I'm new to programming. I recently read that:

> Your program should have almost all functionality encapsulated in
>   either functions or class methods

This makes it seems as though I should not have both functions and methods. I have also read that methods should be short and simple.

Well, I've recently made a small program that downloads images from blogs. I used classes and the OOP approach because I need to inherit certain things.

However, because the methods should be short and do one thing, my program cannot do much.
My question is, if I'm trying to use a pure OOP approach, how is it possible to avoid writing functions?

My script follows basically this pattern:

```
class Tumblr(object):

    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def get_posts(self):
        """Use tumblr api to return a user's posts."""
        return client['blog']['posts']

    def parse_images(self):
       """Returns images."""
        images = []
        for post in posts:
            if 'image' in post:
                images.append(post['image'])
        return images

    def parse_videos(self):
      """Returns videos."""

def main():
            # this is a function, and thus not OOP?
```

I also have other classes for different website APIs, and also a Downloader class that actually downloads the files to disk and to the proper directory. The issue is, right now all I have are these isolated classes and methods.

I thought about creating a `main` function that can also use other functions, but again, I don't think this is correct OOP.

How can I actually get work done without writing functions? (The textbooks I've read have said functions shouldn't be used in pure OOP, if I am using methods.)

Comment: Do you understand the difference between functions and methods?

Comment: _Short and simple_ does not mean _too short to be useful_.  Sometimes methods are complicated.

Comment: A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds. Write a function if you feel it's appropriate; your computer will not melt. Refactor later if necessary.

Comment: "Your program should have almost all functionality encapsulated in either functions or class methods" should really end with "in functions **and/or** class methods". There's nothing wrong with having functions that aren't part of a class if it doesn't make sense to have the function tied to a specific object. A `main` function, like in your example, certainly does not need to be part of a class.

Comment: You should watch the PyCon video "[stop writing classes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)" to get some real-world perspective on this.

Comment: OOP has some very good principles but as with most things you need to see what suits your program and be pragmatic. Going to extremes like creating meaningless classes just so you don't have standalone functions doesn't make your program better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meh, no.

Having a `main()` function is so ubiquitous and required in some languages that using that as a hook to launch is fine - something somewhere has to say 'go'. Though, it is pythonic to implement it as

```
class YourObjectHere(object):
    ###blahblahblah your code here
    ...
    ...

def main():
    MyObj = YourObjectHere(*args, **kwargs)
    OtherObj.do_stuff_with_obj(MyObj)
    #etc etc etc
    ...
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Among other reasons, because this allows you to reuse the code as a module and import it without causing the thing to run every time.

Foolish consistency is consistent, sure, but it's foolish first and foremost. Do what you need to do, but look to the language to ensure that you aren't just duplicating effort. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0 for a great video about when writing a class is a poor idea -- the first rule of thumb typically being, if an object has two methods, and one of them is `__init__()`, it *probably* doesn't *need* to be a class.

Answer (score 5):

Don't go writing classes when a function suffices. Paraphrased from the [Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/);

- Simple is better than complex.
- Practicality beats purity.

In Python you can use many methods of programming; procedural, object-oriented, functional. All have their strength and weaknesses. But all have their uses.

If you are struggling to build a pure object-oriented solution to a problem, that may be a sign that you are *Doing It Wrong* and that objects aren't the best solution to that particular problem.

You should employ the method that best fits the problem.

Jack Diederich's PyCon presentation "stop writing classes" contains some good examples. A telling and in hindsight obvious lesson was that if your object has two methods, one of which is `__init__`, it is really a function in disguise.

Comment: Yep, it's a classic. I found it very instructive.

Answer (score 2):

> Your program should have ***almost*** all functionality encapsulated in either functions or class methods

Notice the word "almost". That's your loophole right there.

This rule you cited, is a "rule of thumb". It's a suggestion, to follow as much as possible, and as long as it makes sense. If you have to make exceptions sometimes, that's ok, it's not the end of the world. And that's why the "almost" word is there.

And if the word "almost" wasn't there, general statements like this are never 100% true, there are always justifiable exceptions. That sentence wants to put your on the right path, it really doesn't mean you have to follow it religiously 100%.

Comment: Also, in the context of Python, "class method" and "method" are not interchangeable so the quote is likely taken from some other context.